# What does the notation $f^*(x)$ mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I'm doing an assignment for my calculus course. I don't need help with the question. But I've never come across that notation $f^*(x)\;.\;$ See the following picture :

[image]

I can't find anything in my book about it. Is it just an arbitrary use of a symbol ?

Comment: It is literally defined in your image.

Comment: I agree with @Randall ... it is defined in this problem.  So remember it is not a standard notation, and elsewhere it should not be assumed  to have the same meaning.

Comment: Assuming I know what an image is; I don't. But thank you, I'll look that up and explore further.

Comment: Yes, it just there to mean that it is something that is related to $f$, but not $f$ itself.

Comment: The "image" in question is the _picture_ you posted as part of the question. You ask what $f^*$ means, but sure enough right there in the picture it _says_ what it means: $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$, if the limit exists.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My bad, I was assumining the literal definition of an Image. But I get it now. f* is just an arbitrary way of representing something, and not a defined notation    with rules.

Comment: @ndryorku96. It is a defined notation; it's introduced and defined in the picture. But in contrast to notations for the ordinary derivative, like $f'$, it is not a standard notation. The Wikipedia article about [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) uses the notation $f_s.$

Comment: @md2perpe Ah, thank you very much. The math isn't the problem for me; It's just learning all the new jargon and syntax. Your answer cleared up my doubts perfectly.

Comment: @ndryorku96. You will meet a lot of notation. Sometimes it's a standard notation, and sometimes, especially in examples and exercises, it's just a local notation. It can take some time to get used to notations and concepts.

Answer (score 5):

It is defined in your picture, to mean so form of weak derivative. The notation $f^*$ with this definition is not standard (in that the same symbol is used in a lot of different contexts to represent other objects).

Comment: It turns out that use of the word "image" is confusing here, since that word often has a mathematical meaning.